# Change source on click in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mapbox

I am working on Angular project. I have loaded Mapbox map. There is database set up which has some kind of campaigns, each campaign has its own polygon. When user chooses a campaign, it should fire `plotPolygon(coordinates)` function. This function is below in code, and it will add the source for Mapbox (source being coordinates of polygon) with `map.addSource()`. Each time when user clicks on different campaign, source should be changed and different polygon should be added to Mapbox. I think that the previous source should also be deleted at the same time. I'm a bit confused on how to do this. Input variable `polygon` in my case is changing every time when function `plotPolygon` is called. Result I get is that when function is called first time, I get polygon plotted, and on each subsequent call nothing will change, polygon will stay plotted. What it should do is delete old polygon and plot a new one.

This is function which I made:

```
plotPolygon(polygon: any) {
  //PLOTTING polygons
  // Add a data source containing GeoJSON data.
  this.map.addSource('CampPoly', {
    'type': 'geojson',
    'data': {
    'type': 'Feature',
    'geometry': {
    'type': 'Polygon',
    // These coordinates outline CampPoly.
    'coordinates': polygon
    }
    }
    });

    // Add a new layer to visualize the polygon.
  this.map.addLayer({
    'id': 'CampPoly',
    'type': 'fill',
    'source': 'CampPoly', // reference the data source
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
    'fill-color': '#0080ff', // blue color fill
    'fill-opacity': 0.5
    }
    });
    // Add a black outline around the polygon.
  this.map.addLayer({
    'id': 'outline',
    'type': 'line',
    'source': 'CampPoly',
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
    'line-color': '#000',
    'line-width': 3
    }
    });
  }
```